# Proof with the help of natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, natural-deduction

I have some problems trying to proof the following with the help of natural deduction:

$(S\land \lnot T) \lor (\lnot S \land T),~ \lnot (K \land F),~ T \to K \vdash F \to S$

I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Start with a conditional proof.  Assume $F$ with the aim of deriving $S$.  That derivation will use a proof by cases.

Comment: What does $|$ mean in this? Explicitly, $T \rightarrow K| =F$.

Comment: It's nice to see a natural deduction question that is actually natural deduction and not classical logic pretending to be natural deduction.

Comment: @DanielV Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @RyanG Natural deduction was designed with normalizing rules in mind, like $\land$-intro followed by a $\land$-elim can be canceled.   So only "constructive" things can be proven.  And it is common to see people ask for nonconstructive things to be proven in natural deduction which is annoying because then it isn't really natural deduction.

Comment: @DanielV I don't see anything wrong with taking a natural deduction system for intuitionistic logic, adding a rule such as proof by contradiction (if $\Gamma, \lnot P \vdash \bot$ then $\Gamma \vdash P$), and calling that a natural deduction system for classical logic.  To me, the distinguishing feature of natural deduction is focusing on proof rules as opposed to axioms, and especially having ${\rightarrow}I$ be a first-class proof rule instead of a metatheorem.  (And normalizing rules are more related to sequent calculus, which admittedly is very closely related to...

Comment: natural deduction, and also admittedly seems more natural to use for intuitionistic logic than for classical logic, where for the latter you essentially have to allow for multiple consequences on the right of a $\vdash$.)

Comment: "How do I start this problem" is a legitimate question.  Sometimes users say that when they have no understanding of the subject and it is hiding a request for a lecture, but if you look at the comments of the user you can see that clearly isn't the case.  He knows natural deduction, he just needs help knowing what direction to start in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by proving:

$$S \land \lnot T, \lnot (K \land F), T \to K \vdash F \to S$$

as well as proving

$$\lnot S \land T, \lnot (K \land F), T \to K \vdash F \to S$$

That's proof by cases.  Combine the two proofs using $\lor-\text{elim}$ rule.

Comment: Hello, thanks! I did proof the first one, but having some trouble with the second one.

Comment: $$A \vdash B \to C$$ if and only if $$A, B \vdash C$$ look for a contradiction in the assumptions

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was able to solve it now :)

Comment: Daniel, you are now a "trusted user" (defined by $\ge$ 20$ K in rep.  Please start acting thusly.  In particular, please abide by the quality standards expected of answerers, else the [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|37.8015), which I know you have been previously linked to.  Note that such answers are open for downvoting and for flagging moderators, when such answering, which brought you to your current rep, is a general pattern one has exhibited.

Comment: @amWhy I'm guessing you are responding to my answering to a question that was closed.  Well the question shouldn't have been closed.  I'll remind you that the point of the website isn't to solve problems, it is to provide help for individual steps on a problem.  Asking "how do I start" is a legitimate question when that is really what the user needs.  He isn't asking for a lecture, he knows the subject, he really just need help on how to start.  You'll notice I answered in a way that won't help someone unless they really mean "how do I start".

Comment: @amWhy Frankly, I think the main reason this question was closed was that users didn't find it "fun".  You should be criticizing them.